Navigating to a point with cm accuracy
I am due to install some monitoring points for a field experiment. I have a GNSS receiver (Arrow 100) and so can record the location of my monitoring points with a high degree of accuracy. I am expecting them to be very hard to re-locate when I need to find them, and was wondering what others use to navigate back to a point.
Does anyone have experience of using QField connected to a GNSS to re-locate a monitoring point? Is it reliable? I am also wondering what settings I need to sync to make sure that both Arrow 100 and QField are operating with the same projection/co-ordinate systems etc?

Is it possible to install surface markers for your point? Are there visual references that are capturable with a photo? If you have a "normal" GNSS receiver without postprocessing or something like differential GPS, you will only get to meter accuracy of your initial measurement (OK, I see that your receiver uses RTK, Atlas  and SBAS data internally; that part will not be a problem).

Please keep it to one question per question and post a second question for the CRS sync issue.

you need to place visible markers (screws) that are permanent - flags normally indicate underlying utilities (pipes, gas, fibre). example is https://www.sandiegoreader.com/news/2013/mar/20/straight-metal-sidewalk-markers/

Thank you everyone :) Yes, there will be physical markers - they're just going to be hard to find under a lot of vegetation, and I can't use canes due to cattle and machinery also moving over the site.

Paint the markers or attach a flag colored fluro hot pink, that color is easy to find under moderate vegetation if you can get within a metre or two.

Thank you Michael - I'll definitely get some fluro hot pink paint!

If you use QField with Arrow100 to collect the locations of the monitoring points and then use QField with Arrow100 to navigate back to the monitoring points, a mismatch between reference frames doesn't matter because the same mismatch will be present when collecting points and trying to find the points.  Getting the reference frame right only matters if you want to navigate to coordinates you've collected with some other system, or if you want to export your data to another system.
